# How many clauses and objects are there in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrases, clauses

Actually, on account of a festival, I received a mail from my management. I felt that the following sentence in that mail is wrong. Because I can't determine whether it is simple, complex or compound sentence. Please have a look at this sentence and let me know whether it is grammatically correct or not. If possible, please explain it clearly.

> Our team is so blessed to have each other, since we are special in our own way - Creative, Hardworking, Dedicated, Committed, Passionate, so making work fly by.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that *making work fly by* acts as a [compound adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier#Compound_adjectives). We can connect the words with hyphens to make it more readable:

> Our team is so blessed to have each other, since we are special in our own way - Creative, Hardworking, Dedicated, Committed, Passionate, so **making-work-fly-by**.

It is a complex sentence, because it has the conjunction **since** in the beginning of the dependent clause "since we are special in our own way ..".

There are two clauses in the sentence, with the second clause including a list of adjectival words illustrating the adjective **special**.

These words- *Creative, hardworking.." - are *appositive adjectives*:

> **Appositive adjective:** a traditional grammatical term for an adjective (or a series of adjectives) that follows a noun and, like a nonrestrictive appositive, is set off by commas or dashes. ([from](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Appositive-Adjective.htm) About.com)

Comment: So,is the main clause (Our team is so blessed to have each other) grammatically correct.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but, well, it looks grammatically correct to me. The main clause seems quite normal. I'd thought it was the "making work fly by" that made you curious.

Comment: Is it (Our team is so blessed to have each other) passive or active in form

Comment: Yes then is it necessary to put "have" in that sentence

Comment: can you convert the sentence into active form

Comment: Correction: I thought it is in the passive voice, [but it is in the active](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/correct-active-form-of-the-following-sentence). My mistake.

Comment: No problem, you make my brain to think