# Active construction of 'Our team is so blessed...'?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, passive-voice, active-voice

Would anybody specify the active form of the following passive sentence.

> Our team is so blessed to have each other

Also please let me know the significance of "have" in the above sentence.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: My excuses for calling this construction *passive*. (0:

Comment: See def#3 here for *have*: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have   -- the (members of) the team have each other *as* team-mates. They share that relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sentence, 'blessed' has the idea of 'fortunate. 'Our team is blessed' is not really a passive construction.

If you are deeply religious, you may feel that it *is* passive, suggesting "God has blessed our team", but you then need to change the rest of the sentence to something like "in giving us each other".

Comment: What about "please let me know the significance of 'have' in the above sentence"?

Answer (score -3):

active voices are the doer's of the sentence's passive is the receiver there are two main subjects in active an passive sentence's there is two subjects the active the person who does the action 
example mia sweeps the kitchen
mia was the one doing the action she is the first subject now for passive it is the receiverthe sentence the kitchen was the receiver of the sweeping so that is active and passive

Comment: That is not what those terms mean. "Mia swept the kitchen" is a sentence in active voice, while "The kitchen was swept" is in passive voice. Mia and the kitchen are neither active *nor* passive voices.